# Microsoft Japanese IME - Disable Alt + `

Tags: windows-7, input, ime, japanese

I have been using Alt + ` frequently in one of my applications.
However, enabling Japanese IME input has messed up this combination because it toggles between alpha and hiragana ([Microsoft IME + Japanese: Force Hiragana input by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/180188/microsoft-ime-japanese-force-hiragana-input-by-default)).

Any ideas on how to disable this key? I could not find it in the keyboard bindings.

Comment: [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) should be able to allow you to map it to some other key or key-combination.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but learning AutoHotKey seems like overkill for this. Perhaps there is a setting I can't find in the Japanese IME?

Comment: Perhaps, but AHK is useful for many other things and might be worth the trouble. See also [this](http://superuser.com/questions/180188/microsoft-ime-japanese-force-hiragana-input-by-default) question.

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft IME for Japanese language input but "ALT + '" does not toggle between alpha and hiragana! I thought that this might be because I have set my IME key settings to "ATOK" key settings (in IME properties, "Editing Controls" tab - translated back from the Japanese since my system is Japanese) since I was used to using ATOK prior to the release of IME.

However, returning my IME key settings to "IME" settings.  None of keys in any of "Microsoft IME" "IME standard" "VJE" "WX" or "ATOK" (the complete list of possible ket settings, seems to include the "ALT + '" on my machine.

However, in any event  fine grained key settings are possible in this same tab, so anyone who has problems with IME shortcut keys being duplicated in an app can change their IME key settings to whatever they like. I would have posted an image but I lack the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I am just using the Google Japanese IME now: [www.google.co.jp/ime/](http://www.google.co.jp/ime/)

Comment: Can you provide a brief description of this software? Link-only answers aren't very useful on their own.